# PHP: limit items to 10 when filling an array

Tags: php, arrays, limit

I am using the following to create a two-dimensional array from a simpleXML string, which works fine so far:

```
$dataRaw = array();

foreach($objRanking->history as $history) { if($history->groupName == "currentMonth") {
    $dataRaw[(string)$history->groupName->item] = (int)$history->groupName->groupCount;
}}
```

**The Array looks as follows:**

```
Array ( [item1] => 2 [item2] => 3 [item3] => 5 [item4] => 7 [item5] => 11 [item6] => 13 [item7] => 17 [item8] => 19 [item9] => 23 [item10] => 29 [item11] => 31 [item12] => 37 )
```

Is there a way I can limit this to maximum 10 items within the array and then summarise all remaining items as [Others] with the value as the sum of the remaining values ?

Many thanks for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: How about writing an `if` statement for such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initailize a counter and keep on incrementing it on each iteration.  On each iteration, check if the counter is below 10 - if so, add the data into the array `$dataRaw` as usual. When the counter value is above 10, start adding them to a new array (`$restOfTheItems` here). Once the loop has finished, you can simply create a new index, sum the array values and assign it.

```
$dataRaw = array();
$restOfTheItems = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($objRanking->history as $history) { 
    if($i <= 10) {
        if($history->groupName == "currentMonth") {
            $dataRaw[(string)$history->groupName->item] = (int)$history->groupName->groupCount;
        }
    } else {
        $restOfTheItems[] = (int)$history->groupName->groupCount;
    } 
    $i++;
}

$dataRaw['Others'] = array_sum($restOfTheItems);
```

Comment: Saw this the second I was going to press post. Yours is more elegant than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

Sure. To do this after the fact slice the array in two, summarize the second chunk and append it to the first:

```
if (count($dataRaw) > 10) {
    $firstTen = array_slice($dataRaw, 0, 10, true);
    $others = array_slice($dataRaw, 10, null, true);

    $dataRaw = $firstTen;
    $dataRaw['Others'] = array_sum($others);
}
```

You can of course also do this during initial processing:

```
foreach($objRanking->history as $history) {
    if($history->groupName == "currentMonth") {
        $groupCount = (int)$history->groupName->groupCount;
        switch(count($dataRaw)) {
            case 11:
                // we already have "Others", so sum the counts
                $dataRaw['Others'] += $groupCount;
                break;
            case 10:
                // we already have 10 items, so add "Others"
                $dataRaw['Others'] = $groupCount;
                break;
            default:
                // less than 10 existing items, add one
                $dataRaw[(string)$history->groupName->item] = $groupCount;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```